# How to switch Chrome's way of opening tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs, tabs

I want to know how can I make Chrome open the tabs in the foreground when I Cmd+click on links, and in the background when I Shift+Cmd+click on them.

Currently it works the opposite way, but since I use much more the foreground tab opening, I rather use only Cmd key for that.

I've searched throughout Chrome's extensions but didn't find any that does this. There are some that set the Cmd+click to open tabs in the foreground BUT then Shift+Cmd+click ALSO opens tabs in the foreground, leaving you without no background-opening option.

I really have a hard time understanding why did Google think it was better to open the tabs always as background tabs. To me (and to Apple it seems) it's much more logical to use the least amount of keys for the most used functions. In Safari you open in foreground ONLY with Cmd+click and in the background with Shift+Cmd+click. And there's even an option in the settings to switch between both.

So hence my question :)

Cheers!

EDIT: I found 3 extensions that used to do this ([Tabs Quick Open](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-quick-open/nmbejfggeihbilalibpboiobehkkaaic/related), [Open Tabs in Foreground](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-tabs-in-foreground/bmnanfhdjbcilhippcdfbhfpfoipgjgm), [Tab Activate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-activate/jlmadbnpnnolpaljadgakjilggigioaj/related)) but don't work no more.

Comment: Here's an extension from 2017 which I haven't tested : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-to-the-front/hiembaoomcehoiehhdldabfgnmphappc?hl=en

Comment: @ChristopherHostage I think it's the closest! It doesn't work with Shift+Cmd but one can temporarily disable the extension to use it in the standard way. Thank you very much! :D

Comment: Personally I mostly use "open in background" as this disturbs the reading focus much less. I stay on the page I am reading from while the new tabs is waiting for me. If I occasionally need to look at the new page now, I just use ctrl-shift-click.